# OnKeyDown and OnBackPressed Combination

Tags: android

Why do I need to return `true` in `onKeyDown()`, to make `onBackPressed()` work?
It's conflicts with the documentation.

[documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

Comment: Give a link to the parts of the documentation you think it conflicts with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a little experiment to confirm that.

your right it seems not confirm the documentation.

here the used code :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.w("TEST", "I'm CALLED !");
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

when onKeyDown returns false, onBackPressed is not called.

We have to notice that onBackPressed is never called if we don't call super.onKeyDown()
so I guess we have to see that as : onBackPressed is called as part as the onKeyDownCall so shouldn't be triggered if the onKeyDown doesn't manage the event (returns false).

Comment: I didn't make myself clear : Since the  onBackPressed is called as part as the onKeyDownCall, the returned boolean concerns it as well. if it returns true, the Back press was taken into account and the onBackPressed is called.